# How to I access an element within my classes's method? (Text based game)

Tags: python, text

So right now i'm making a Text Based Game for a School project, and I have an issue where I can't access my player's location. The error i get is

```
playerInput = input("You are currently in", player.location, ".", player.location, "is", player.location.description)
builtins.TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 6
```

I thought that I could fix this issue by just  passing a single argument, but i'm not sure how to do that. While there are other issues in my code, this is my biggest one at the moment. Knowing this and looking at the following code, how can I fix this issue?

```
# Pope Code--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#



# Variables------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
clock = 24.00

gameExit = False
gameTick = True

playername = "PlaceHolder"
playerbag = []
playerhealth = 10
playerlocation = "PlaceHolder"


# Functions------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

def nextTurn(clock):
    gameTick = True
    if clock < 24.00:
        clock += 1.00

# Items----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
class item():

    def __init__ (self, name, description, effect):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.effect = effect
# Abilities ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
class ability():

    def __init__(self, name, description, usedescription, damage, accuracy, effect):
        self. name = name
        self.description = description
        self.usedescription = usedescription
        self.damage = damage
        self.accuracy = accuracy

Psywave = ability(
    "Psywave",
    "A psyonic move",
    "This move does nothing",
    "5",
    "70",
    "No additonal effect"
)

class entity:
    def __init__(self, name, description, bag, health, psyonics, abilities):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.bag = bag
        self.health = health
        self.psyonics = psyonics
        self.abilities = abilities

testMonster = entity(
    "Test Monster",
    "A monster used for Testing"
    [5],
    5,
    0.25,
    Psywave,
    Psywave
)
#Locations------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

class Zone():
    def __init__(self, name, description, entities, nearby, actions):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.entities = entities
        self.nearby = nearby
        self.actions = actions

testZone = Zone(
    "Test Zone",
    "This is the placeholder description",
    testMonster,
    "Nothing is nearby",
    "These are the actions you may complete"
)

Forest = Zone(
    "Frenzied Forest",
    "This is the placeholder description",
    testMonster,
    "testZone",
    "These are the actions you may complete"

)

# Entities-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

class player:

    def __init__(self, name, description, bag, location, health, psyonics, abilities):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.bag = bag
        self.location = location
        self.health = health
        self.psyonics = psyonics
        self.abilities = abilities
player = player(
    "Default",
    "This is the lplayer description",
    [],
    testZone,
    20,
    0.05,
    Psywave
)



# Player Data----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
playerInput = "This is the placeholder string"
playerBag = []
playerHealth = 10
placeHolder = ["Test"]

# Graphics-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

def startMenu():
    print("===================================================================")
    print("                                                                   ")
    print("                Welcome to The Shroud                              ")
    print("                                                                   ")
    print("                                                                   ")
    print("                  Enter Anything to continue                       ")
    print("                                                                   ")
    print("                                                                   ")
    playerInput = print("Type Here:                                           ")

# Game Loop------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

if gameTick == True and gameExit == False:

    gameTick = False

    playerInput = input("You are currently in", player.location, ".", player.location, "is", player.location.description)

    if playerInput not in player.location.actions:
        print("You cannot perform that action")

    elif playerInput == "End Turn":
        nextTurn()

    elif playerInput == "Bag":
        print("You look into your black backpack. You see", player.bag)

    elif playerInput == "Observe":
        playerInput = print("What would you like to observe?")
        if playerInput == "My items":
            playerInput = print("Which of your items would you like to see? You may look at", player.bag)
            if playerInput in player.bag:
                print(playerInput.description)
            else:
                print("You do not have that item!")
        elif playerInput == "Surroundings":
            print("You use the Sight observe your surroundings. you see a", player.location.description)

    elif playerInput == "Explore":
        playerInput = print("Where would you like to explore?", player.location.nearby)
        if playerInput in player.location.nearby:
            playerlocation = playerInput

if gameExit == True:
    print("You have exited the game")
```

Answer (score 2):

`input` takes only one argument, the input prompt.  You can handle this in either of two ways.  The easy one is to print the prompt separately, *then* ask for the input:

```
print("You are currently in", 
      player.location, ".", player.location,
      "is", player.location.description)
playerInput = input()
```

The other is to build the prompt as a single string, as the syntax requires.

```
playerInput = input("You are currently in" +
      str(player.location) + "." + str(player.location) +
      "is" + player.location.description)
```

Comment: This helped, however, instead of saying that the player is in "Test Zone" I get this:                           You are currently in<__main__.Zone object at 0x0000019038BC54E0>.<__main__.Zone object at 0x0000019038BC54E0>isThis is the placeholder description

Comment: Yes, that's the *next* problem with your code: `player.location` is a Zone object, but you've tried to use it as a string.  A separate problem warrants a separate question.  This time, please follow the posting guidelines.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
StackOverflow is not a coding, review, or tutorial resource.